# How to render a different widget in case of onAdFailedToLoad event with flutter_google_ad_manager plugin?

Tags: flutter

i use flutter_google_ad_manager plugin. In case of onAdFailedToLoad i want to render a different widget instead of the DFPBanner Widget. How can i do that? When i call a widget inside onAdFailedToLoad: (errorCode) {...} it does not get rendered.. why is that?

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 16),
  child: DFPBanner(
    isDevelop: false,
    //testDevices: MyTestDevices(),
    adUnitId: '/XXXXXXXX/MyAdunit',
    adSize: DFPAdSize.MEDIUM_RECTANGLE,
    onAdFailedToLoad: (errorCode) {
      // how to render different widget in case of no fill    
      return Text("render some other widget here");
    },
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a function that renders the widget based on a value, let's say you got a `boolean` flag to check which widget to render, the function would be as follows:

```
_renderWidget() {
 if(flag) {
  return DFPBanner(
    isDevelop: false,
    //testDevices: MyTestDevices(),
    adUnitId: '/XXXXXXXX/MyAdunit',
    adSize: DFPAdSize.MEDIUM_RECTANGLE,
    onAdFailedToLoad: (errorCode) {
      setState((){
       flag = false;
      })
    },
  ),
 } else {
   return Text("render some other widget here");
 }
```

}

Then inside your `Container` you build it's child using that function:

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 16),
  child: _renderWidget()
),
```

Of course this needs to be done inside an `StatefulWidget` and you need to declare `bool flag = true;` variable in it's `State`. Hope this helps.